# Editing is Irritating

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

As everyday newbies visits stackoverflow and Ask Questions which are badly formatted and we goes to edit the question.
But sometimes when I make edit and try to submit it, it says me that another edit is pending approval my concern here is that why at the first point it allows me to edit and when I edit, it doesn't allow me to submit it.

In another case I tried to edit a question but it shows me that someone else is already editing it. 
I want them to say the same when there is a approval pending edit.

Comment: That's not possible; maybe another person submitted their edit faster than you while you were editing - your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: May be you didn't get me. That's not possible that someone submitted an edit faster. Because when you're editing a question other people can't access edit option.

Comment: @Talha Giving everyone the ability to prevent anyone else from ever editing a post is *extremely* open to abuse and misuse.

Comment: I'm not here trying to prevent someone from edit.

Comment: Please ensure your edits use proper grammar, there are several grammatical errors in this question

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I don't correct grammar in questions just formatting and spellings.

Comment: When you’re editing brand-new questions, you’re bound to hit race conditions. Stack Overflow has a *lot* of users. There are plenty of other eyes who see those same typos and formatting mistakes, and immediately try to fix them.

Comment: @Code Gray another thing I want to ask here that who review our edits?

Comment: I don't get pinged when you misspell my name. Anyone who has full editing privileges can review suggested edits, so that would be [anyone with 2,000 reputation or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). There is a review queue for suggested edits accessible at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits (you won't be able to access it, though, as you don't have the privilege to review suggested edits). A post with a pending edit is also indicated by changing the "edit" link to "edit (1)", and a user with the appropriate privileges can review that edit directly there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When an edit is already pending, that's exactly what the system does; tell you it's pending, and won't allow you to edit.  Even those over 2K with full edit privileges can't edit until the current one is completed.

What likely happened is that you started editing prior to someone else who did the same.  They managed to get their edit completed before you, and submitted it.  You then ran into the error message, because, by design, a post can't have more than a single pending edit.

An edit is only pending once it has been submitted.  Before that, any number of editors can make edits.  Only one can submit, however.

Comment: In that case why I got editing option enabled.
Because when someone is editing a question other people can't edit it.

Comment: Please read my last paragraph.

Comment: @talha not exactly. When your edit is *in the queue*, no one else can edit. When you have opened the edit option, your edit isn't in the queue.

Comment: That makes sense now.